# Paw opens link in external browser

Tags: paw-app

When developing endpoints I need to follow a rather complex/cumbersome login process to authenticate with our gatekeeper.

For this I open the developer login page in Paw. It opens inside paw and renders the content properly. If I then click the button to actually login and an external browser is opened causing Paw to loose track of the proper cookies.

I wonder if it would be possible to keep the request inside Paws embedded browser so the cookies are not lost and I can continue testing my endpoints.

Comment: Interesting point! I would definitively be happy to add such a feature. It probably should be an in-app browser, that let you navigate, capture cookies, and store them. I like the idea: I was looking for a nice way to make this possible, and I think you gave me some valuable input! Thanks!

Comment: That would be awesome! If you have something and need me to test it let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to login using cookie-based auth, in Paw 2.1, you can use this hack: go to your web browser with developer mode enabled and login on the website. Then, in the Inspector / Debugger, go to Cookies (in Chrome/Safari: inspector is Cmd+Option+I, then tab "Resources" then "Cookies"). Copy the session/login cookie. Go back to Paw and add a "Cookie: mySessionCookie=value" header. It should do the trick.

*Note: that's a hacky method. As mentioned in my earlier comment, a nicer way is to come.*

Comment: Unfortunately there are 6 cookies involved. For now my workaround is using the Chrome extension DHC but I prefer to use Paw of course. So I hope you have some luck implementing the feature mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Yeah, I'm very excited about adding this feature. Not sure if it will be possible in the next version, but for sure the one coming right after.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri I'd love to see this feature too, it would be really helpful for manual testing. Any updates on this?

Comment: Yes, we're going to implement a Chrome extension for this!