# How do I login via a website not using OAuth (or similar) using Paw?

Tags: paw-app

I have some endpoints that only work when you’re signed in, but not using OAuth or similar – it’s a web login. How can I login?

Comment: You are probably looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690736/paw-opens-link-in-external-browser/28694072

Answer (score 0):

This is called HTTP Basic authentication and Paw has some documentation for this here: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/HTTP_Basic_Auth.  You need to add a header to your request under the Authorization category called "HTTP Basic Auth" and this is all explained in the above link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply – I’m not using Basic Auth either, it’s a login like say Stack Overflow or Twitter.com has a login.

Comment: Oh so sorry.  You will have to know the format of the POST request that is sent when the user submits the login form.  Then you can use Paw to emulate that once before you send your other Paw requests.  Perhaps you can use the Chrome, Firefox, or Safari dev inspector to see what happens when the user logins and then create a request like it in Paw.

Comment: Are you able to share the site url?

Comment: I think this question is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690736/paw-opens-link-in-external-browser/28694072